# Knowing the eigenvalues for A find the matrix A

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I know the eigenvalues for a matrix. Let's say they are 2 and 1. How can I find the matrix A for them (all members of A are not null) ?

Comment: I have to give just an example. Av=λv doesnt provide enough equations to find A

Comment: If  $D$ is the diagonal matrix with desired eigenvalues and $C$ a "generic" matrix, $CDC^{-1}$ will work outside of exceptional cases. (An entry of $CDC^{-1}$ being zero is a polynomial equation in terms of the entries of $C$; so it either holds identically or holds only on a set of measure zero.) Admittedly, this does not help when you want a constructive approach.

Comment: @abc32 I'd just blindly take $\text{diag}(1,2)$ and compute $P\text{diag}(1,2)P^{-1}$ until I found an appropriate $P$.

Comment: There are infinitely many such matrices, even for one with integer entries.
eg. $(\begin{smallmatrix}a+3&-1\\(a+1)(a+2)&-a\end{smallmatrix})$ for any integer $a > 0$.
To find a $2 \times 2$ matrix of such form, just use the facts: $\text{tr}(A) = 1+2 = 3$ and $\det(A) = 1\times 2 = 2$ to eliminate two degree of freedom from the 4 entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try working backwards from the characteristic polynomial (although this probably isn't a great method)

If $\lambda = 1, 2$ then

$$\begin{align}
(\lambda - 1)(\lambda - 2) &= 0 \\
\implies \lambda^{2} - 3\lambda + 2 &= 0 \\
\implies \lambda^{2} - 3\lambda - 10 + 12 &= 0 \ \ \ (*) \\
\implies (5 - \lambda)(-2 - \lambda) - (-12) &= 0 \\
\end{align}$$

Which gives us the matrix

$$A = \begin{pmatrix}
  5 & -6 \\
  2 & -2 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

But at $(*)$ I just added an *arbitrary* number $(-12)$ so I could factorise the $\lambda$ polynomial. I could have chosen any number that corresponded with me maintaining eigenvalues of $1$ and $2$.

Answer (score 0):

take any two column vectors that are not multiples of each other. for example $\pmatrix{1\\1}, \pmatrix{k\\1}, k \neq 1.$

form the matrix product  $A = \dfrac{1}{1-k}\pmatrix{1&k\\1&1}\pmatrix{2&0\\0&1}\pmatrix{1&-1\\-k&1}$ wil have the  eigenvalues $2, 1$ 
you can make up many other matrices that will do the job. all these matrices are similar to the diagonal matrix and is of the form $SDS^{-1}$ wher $D$ is the diagonal matrix with entries $2$ and $1.$