# Find general solution for 3x3 matrix A given only eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given only distinct eigenvalues (ie.-1,2,3) of a of some unknown 3x3 matrix A, can a general solution for A be found?

With the eigenvalues given a solution could be a diagonal matrix

A =\begin{bmatrix}-1&0&0\\0&2&0\\0&0&3\end{bmatrix}
This can be generalized to:

A =\begin{bmatrix}a&0&0\\0&b&0\\0&0&c\end{bmatrix}

If A is not a diagonal matrix is it possible to find A?

Comment: Two distinct matrices can have the same eigenvalues. For example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity

Comment: Also see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1129150/knowing-the-eigenvalues-for-a-find-the-matrix-a/1129178#1129178) for answers on a similar problem.

Comment: The general solution is $P^{-1}AP$, where $A$ is your diagonal matrix, and $P$ is an arbitrary invertible $3\times3$ matrix.